# gstreamer: no output from custom pipeline (replacing playbin)

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to replace `playbin` in an application with my own pipeline, because I need to add filters to the video. Here is what I tried:

```
#     self.pipeline = gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin", None)
#     self.pipeline.set_property("uri", "appsrc://")
self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline.new("player")
source = gst.ElementFactory.make("uridecodebin", "decodebin")
source.set_property("uri", "appsrc://")
self.pipeline.add(source)

aqueue = gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "aqueue")        
aconverter = gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "aconverter")        
asink = gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink", "audiosink")
self.pipeline.add(aqueue)
self.pipeline.add(aconverter)
self.pipeline.add(asink)
source.link(aqueue)
aqueue.link(aconverter)
aconverter.link(asink)

vqueue = gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "vqueue")        
vconverter = gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "vconverter")
vsink = gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink", "videosink")
self.pipeline.add(vqueue)
self.pipeline.add(vconverter)
self.pipeline.add(vsink)
source.link(vqueue)
vqueue.link(vconverter)
vconverter.link(vsink)
```

Later I connect to the source's `source-setup` signal, and then to the `need-data` signal to feed it with data. This works with `playbin`, i.e. an output window opens and shows the video. With my custom pipeline nothing happens - no window is opened and of course I can't see anything.

Why is that so and how can I fix it?

I have also tried removing all the audio stuff and using only the video elements, with the same result. I don't even really need audio for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uridecodebin has dynamic pads. They are only created when streaming starts because it needs to demux/decode to get to know how many pads it needs to expose. Check https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-pads.html#section-pads-dynamic

For debugging it is also good practice to look at the gstreamer logs or check the pipeline bus for error messages. It likely would have reported a not-linked error. Or checking the return for the link calls would tell you it was failing.

Anyway, you can just use playbin and set the `video-filter` property.

Comment: Linking dynamically worked well, I see an output window now. Setting playbin properties didn't work yet though, but I'll try to do that as well just to see which way is more suitable for my application

Comment: Check the debug logs to see if it helps understanding the issue with the property

Comment: the debug output says that there's no such property. I guess that should go into another question though.